# How can I post multiple files in Laravel using Guzzle?

Tags: php, html, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to upload files to an external server using JWT to authenticate. My form looks like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('operations.photos-for-families.upload', [$operation, $current->index]) }}" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type="file" name="photos[]" multiple="multiple">
    @csrf
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

My route looks like this:

```
    Route::post('{operation}/{index}/photos-for-families/upload', function (Request $request, string $operation, int $index) {
        if (!opExists($operation, $index) || !$request->has('photos') || empty($request->allFiles()))
            return back()->withErrors(['Oops. Sorry, something went wrong.']);

        $response = Http::attach('photos', $request->allFiles())
            ->post("https://cdn.mydomain.co.uk/gallery/{$operation}/{$index}/upload", [
                'token' => JWT::encode([
                    'iss' => 'https://mydomain.co.uk',
                    'aud' => 'https://cdn.mydomain.co.uk',
                    'iat' => time(),
                    'exp' => time() + 30, // 30 seconds expiration in-case of intercepts or re-use
                    'nbf' => time() - ((60 * 60) * 24),
                    'data' => [
                        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                    ]
                ], 'MY_KEY')
            ]);

        var_dump($response);
    })->name('operations.photos-for-families.upload');
```

However, It seems I cannot send multiple photos in one single request.

> InvalidArgumentException 
>  Invalid resource type: array

I am reading the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#multi-part-requests) but can't find how to attach multiple photos. I know I do not verify the MimeType of the file, because its in development and this will happen once working.

Any help appreciated. The code on the `cdn` server looks like this:

```
Route::post('/gallery/{operation}/{index}/upload', function (Request $request, string $operation, int $index) {

    if(!$request->has('token'))
        return redirect()->away('https://mydomain.co.uk');

    try {
        $access = JWT::decode($request->get('token'), 'MY_KEY', ['HS256']);

        if ($access->iss !== 'https://mydomain.co.uk' ||
            $access->aud !== 'https://cdn.mydomain.co.uk') {
            abort(404);
        }

        if ($access->nbf > time())
            return redirect()->away('https://mydomain.co.uk');

        if ($access->exp < time())
            return redirect()->away('https://mydomain.co.uk');

        $files = [];

        foreach ($request->allFiles() as $file):
            $name = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', Carbon::now()) . '-' . Str::random(30);
            $file->storeAs("protected/{$operation}/{$index}/", "{$name}.{$file->getClientOriginalExtension()}");
            tap(PhotosAccess::create([
                'user_id' => $access->data->user_id,
                'operation' => $operation,
                'index' => $index,
                'path' => "{$name}.{$file->getClientOriginalExtension()}",
            ]), function(PhotosAccess $photo) {
                $files[] = $photo->id;
            });
        endforeach;

        /**
         * TODO: Create endpoint on mydomain as confirmation
         */

        return redirect()->away('https://mydomain.co.uk/dashboard');
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        abort(404);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach multiple files by using `attach()`. Attach is a recursive function. check [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php#L228)

```
$response = Http::withToken(/*your whole JWT process*/); // will add a jwt token

foreach($request->allFiles() as $key => $files)
    foreach($files as $file)
        $response->attach('photos['. Str::random(20).']', file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()), Str::random(20) . '.jpg');

$response = $response->post($url);
```