# Only arrays and Traversables can be unpacked error with a guzzle HTTP POST request with multiple files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, guzzle

So I'm trying to do a POST request with guzzle with multiple files. The user has selected one or more files in a form and hit submit to POST the form. The following code gets run in the controller after that:

```
public function upload(Request $request){

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'file-upload' => 'required',
        'file-upload.*' => 'file|mimes:mp3,wav,mp4'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/upload-files')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
    
    $names = [];
    if($request->hasFile('file-upload')) {

        foreach ($request->file('file-upload') as $file) {
            if(file_exists($file)){
                $name= $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $names[] = $name;
            }
        }
    }

    $api = env('CUSTOMERLYTICS_API').'/v1/upload';

    $response = Http::attach(
        $names, $request->file('file-upload')
        )->post($api, [
            'name' => Auth::user()->name.date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            'company' => Auth::user()->id,
            'api' => false,
            'language' => 'nl'
        ]);

    //ddd($response->json());

    return view('dashboard');
```

It goes wrong at the $names part:

```
Http::attach(
        $names, $request->file('file-upload')
```

I get the error: "Only arrays and Traversables can be unpacked" and get the following stack trace:

```
/**

 * Attach a file to the request.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $name
 * @param  string|resource  $contents
 * @param  string|null  $filename
 * @param  array  $headers
 * @return $this
 */

public function attach($name, $contents = '', $filename = null, array $headers = [])
{
    if (is_array($name)) {
        foreach ($name as $file) {
            $this->attach(...$file);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    $this->asMultipart();

    $this->pendingFiles[] = array_filter([
        'name' => $name,
        'contents' => $contents,
        'headers' => $headers,
        'filename' => $filename,
    ]);

    return $this;
```

Which I find weird, since $names is an array. I've checked it with ddd($names) after the foreach statement in my code and it showed an array with the original file names, just like how it's supposed to be.

How can I solve this error? Or what is a better way to POST multiple files in one request?

Comment: If this does not work I have to debug it, if you do not want to change names you can use foreach to traverse over various files, take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68580591/9471283) answer as example

Comment: Also check your file extensions maybe some of them are not accessible i.e why it can't be traversed if you are saying all you are sending is array

Comment: was the issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

For me I try to merge 2 arrays to one eg. `$cateogories = [];` and `$products` = null.

```php
$merged = [...$categories, ...$products];
```

The error is causing when `$products` is `null`;

To solve this just assign `$products` variable to `[]` or check it.

Answer (score -1):

The main issue at hand is that you are attempting to assign data (parsed values from JSON or an array) to an object variable that has not been instantiated or handled yet.